# Compare strings from different text files in c

Tags: c, string

I have two text files test1.txt and test2.txt. Each of them have multiple strings. I would like compare them and print if they are same or different.
My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char temp[100];

char const *t1;
char const *t2;

FILE *fp1=fopen("test1.txt","r");
while((t1=fgets(temp,sizeof(temp),fp1))!=NULL){
     FILE *fp2=fopen("test2.txt","r");
     while((t2=fgets(temp,sizeof(temp),fp2))!=NULL){
          if(strcmp(t1,t2)==0){
             printf("same\n");
             }
           else{
             printf("Differ\n");
             }
          }
     fclose(fp2);
     }
fclose(fp1);
}
```

And text file test1.txt:

```
100100001
1111
```

test2.txt:

```
10101001
1001
```

The above mentioned code gives the following output:

```
same
same
same
same
```

Which is clearly wrong!

What am I doing wrong here? How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I fixed the code. The following code works fine but please let me know if a better solution exists:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char temp1[100];
char temp2[100];

char const *t1;
char const *t2;

FILE *fp1=fopen("test1.txt","r");
while((t1=fgets(temp1,sizeof(temp1),fp1))!=NULL){
     FILE *fp2=fopen("test2.txt","r");
     while((t2=fgets(temp2,sizeof(temp2),fp2))!=NULL){
          if(strcmp(t1,t2)==0){
             printf("same\n");
             }
           else{
             printf("Differ\n");
             }
          }
     fclose(fp2);
     }
fclose(fp1);
}
```

Comment: You read a line from f1 into temp. Then you read a line from f2 into temp. Then you check whether temp and temp contain the same string, which obviously they do because they're the same variable.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it and changed the code (update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
        char temp[100];

        char t1[100];
        char t2[100];

        FILE *fp1=fopen("test1.txt","r");
        FILE *fp2=fopen("test2.txt","r");

        while((fgets(t1,100,fp1)!= NULL) && (fgets(t2,100,fp2)!= NULL))
        {

                if(strcmp(t1, t2) == 0)
                {
                        printf("same\n");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("NOT same\n");
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: fgets(t1,1000,fp1) , why 1000 than 100.

Comment: Variable char temp[100] is not used. Also it's better to use sizeof(t1) instead of 100 as constant.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use t1 in while loop 
When it f1 is not equal to null then copy first string in f1 to temp1
Similarly when f2.txt not equal to null  then cipy first string in f2 to temp2
Now compare strings temp1 and temp2 using strcmp(temp1,temp2) 
Do this until either f1.txt or f2.txt isequal to null

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.. This helps if others come across the same problem.